# Dynamically add input textbox row by row

Tags: javascript, jquery

All the examples that popped up on this forum do not relate to my current issue,

Currently, we have three rows of textboxes with a possibility of adding more rows later.

Below is sample code:

```
<body>
<div class="bs-example">
    <form class="form-inline" role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label  for="employeename">Employee Name</label><br>
            <input type="email" style="width:250px;" class="form-control" name="employeename" id="employeename" placeholder="Employee name...">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="ttitle">Title</label><br>
            <input type="password" style="width:250px;" class="form-control" name="ttitle" id="ttitle" placeholder="Title...">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputPassword">Password</label><br>
            <input type="password" style="width:250px;"  class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">
        </div><br><br><br>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputName">Name</label><br>
                    <input type="text" style="width:250px;" class="form-control" id="inputName" placeholder="Name">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputAddress">Address</label><br>
                    <input type="text" style="width:250px;" class="form-control" id="inputAddress" placeholder="Address">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputIncome">Income</label><br>
                    <input type="text" style="width:250px;"  class="form-control" id="inputIncome" placeholder="Income">
        </div><br><br><br>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="inputSpouse">Spouse</label>
            <input type="text" style="width:250px;" class="form-control" id="inputSpouse" placeholder="Spouse">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputPassword">Affiliation</label>
            <input type="text" style="width:250px;" class="form-control" id="inputAfil" placeholder="Affilatio n>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputDOB">DOB</label>
            <input type="text" style="width:250px;"  class="form-control" id="inputDOB" placeholder="Date of birth">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
    </form>
    <br>
</div>
</body>
```

Is it possible to have create additional textboxes dynamically row by row?

In other words, per the code above, there are three rows, users may have the need to create additional textboxes for one or more rows but not all the rows.

So, anyone has any ideas how to create additional rows dynamically row by row instead of adding textboxes for all rows at once?

I hope one of you experts can help.

[image]

Comment: You need a button and click handler for adding elements dynamically and appended it into needed element

Comment: Yes you can add dynamic content to DOM easily by jquery

Comment: Every example so far as I indicated in my post adds the textbox in wholesale.

In other words, one click adds rows.

We would like to add it by div because each row is separated by d<div>

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way can be this. You can created dynamic `tr` and append it to `tbody` of a `table`

```js
$(":button").click(function(){
  var str = "<tr>";
  str+="<td><input type=textbox class=txtFirst /></td>";
  str+="<td><input type=textbox class=txtSecond /></td>";
  str += "</tr>";
  $("table tbody").append(str);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type=button value=Add />
<table>
  <tbody>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not being specific about what rows you need to create. In any case, you could use something like ...

https://jsfiddle.net/2nayvcmx/

HTML

```
    <div>
  Employee name
</div>
<div>
  <input type="text" id="employee_name" value="" name="employee_name" />
</div>
<div>
  Employee title
</div>
<div>
  <button id="add_employee_title">
    Add title
  </button>
</div>
<div class="add_employee_title">

</div>
<hr/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button#add_employee_title').click(function() {

    $(this).hide();
    $('div.add_employee_title').html('<input type="text" name="employee_title"/>');
  });
});
```

Comment: fair comment.. I have update my question above with screenshot. The screenshot shows three rows. However, it could grow to as many as 9. I just wanted to show sample so that hopefully, someone can help with a solution that I can use to extent to additional rows.

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: As you can see from the screenshot, some user want additional rows for Name , Address and Income or for Spouse, Affilation and income in which case, we would like them to just add a row only to that row.

Comment: yes, you can still use the code above, that applies to any dynamically created input. just change the place or the logic. with jquery you have endless posibilities. take a look at .html(), .append(), .prepend(). If you would like to add multiple fields just change html(...) with prepend(...); and the name to name="additional[]" you could also put a little X after each input, give the input an increasing id so the user can delete them later. If you consider you would only learn from a written example let me know, but I think it's better for you to give it a shot on writing yourself:D